# Can I use different fonts for each language in React Native?

Tags: react-native, unicode-range

I'm using React Native to create a Korean app.

I want to use different fonts such as Korean and English.
For example, 헬로우 World
In this case, Is there a way to use different fonts?

I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me how.

Comment: <.  Text.  > 헬로우 World <  /Text. >
in this case
I would like to apply "헬로우" and "World"'s font differently.

Comment: i think u are using different characters in each language. should create a json for each language that contains a key:value paire for each world with same key in all files and equivalent value in the language. with changing language u can change json file, font or any thing else

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font-family of the app for different languages.

Based on the user's selected language, change the font-family to something specific. You can store the font family in a centralized store like Redux.

Comment: <.  Text.  > 헬로우 World <  /Text. >
in this case
I would like to apply "헬로우" and "World"'s font differently.